# Does Islam believe in ‘Karma’ or ‘Natural Justice’?

Tags: quran, hadith

Does Islam believe in ‘[**Karma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma)’ or ‘Natural Justice’?

Do Koran and Hadith discuss anything about **Karma**?

Answer (score 2):

Shortly said, no. All Abrahamic religions (Islam, Christianity and Judaism) teach of the Day of Judgement, where everybody will be questioned for their deeds and punished for their bad deeds. After that you either go to hell or heaven. Allah will neither punish nor reward you before the Day of Judgement except if he is willed to do so.

It is not mentioned in a single verse nor hadith (nor in other Abrahamic teaching) of a concept like "Karma". Karma means that you will be instantly rewarded or punished (or after you died and you are resurrected) for your deeds. No Abrahamic religion teaches a concept like this. You have a limited time (your lifetime) and after this time passed (you died) there is no turning back and you won't get a second chance. Allah mentions in the holy Quran:

> Or [lest] it say when it sees the punishment, "If only I had another turn so I could be among the doers of good." (39:58)

A muslim shouldn't believe in believes like that because it is strictly forbidden for him to support/believe in the teachings of other religions (except the teachings of Abrahamic religions):

> Such has been Our way with the messengers We sent before you. And you will find no change in Our way. (Sura al-Israa 17:77)

And Allah knows best.

Comment: But there are verses which indicates the justice for here as well as hereafter , but not universally and hence in a strict sense , it is not same as karma.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes and no.  [The Wikipedia reference for Karma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma) begins with

"refers to the spiritual principle of cause and effect where intent and actions of an individual (cause) influence the future of that individual (effect).Good intent and good deed contribute to good karma and future happiness, while bad intent and bad deed contribute to bad karma and future suffering."

It sounds like Karma is the book of deeds that everyone has. It states in many places in the Quran that "those who believe and perform good deeds (hayir) will be rewarded" and those who reject faith and do evil (sher) will be punished.  This is fundamental to the Islamic faith.  Allah will grant you what you earned.  However, Allah is most merciful. His reward for believer who do good works are proportionally much higher than the punishments for sher.

If the rewards and punishments are not given to a person in this life, see Quran 14:7, he/she will surely get them in the hereafter on "yaum mi deen" (Time of Judgement).  This is where Islam differs from Hinduism on the post-mortem aspects of reward and punishment.  Muslims believe in the Yaum mi Deen and this is fundamental to the faith, whereas Hindus believe post-mortem karma will manifest itself in reincarnation and other forms.

Answer (score -1):

No Allah s.w.t is al-Muntaqim The One who disapproves of wrongdoers. The One who reminds us when our behavior is not right.

The One who is the avenger (such that we need not seek any personal revenge).

The One and Only One who has the right to exact vengeance.
 I will leave a link to where I got this information so you can study for yourself

https://wahiduddin.net/words/99_pages/muntaqim_81.htm